# Wi-Fi driver for Ubuntu on a Mac

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, mac

I am running a MacBook Pro with 2 partitions:  High Sierra and Ubuntu. When I boot up the Ubuntu OS, Wi-Fi doesn't exist. The System option that I am instructed to use to set it up doesn't exist in the Ubuntu software. Do you know which driver I need?

Running Ubuntu Desktop 20

```
       Card Type: AirPort Extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5)  
Firmware Version: Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.190.20.1a4)  
     MAC Address: 88:1f:a1:20:e2:86
```

Comment: Broadcom cards notoriously lack proper drivers on Linux. My server has one, and the only way I got it to work was by manually adding the network in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Trying to use something like Network Manager won't work, and no existing other solutions worked for me, other than editing that file.

Comment: It's hard to say what will help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271818/bcm43142-wifi-adapter-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-20-04 or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230140/wifi-keeps-dropping-out-ubuntu-20-04-and-broadcom-wireless-adaptor  with Broadcom cards always problems